# Recommended usage of Python dictionary, functions as values

Tags: python

I'm looking for some help understanding best practices regarding dictionaries in Python.

I have an example below:

```
def convert_to_celsius(temp, source):
    conversion_dict = {
        'kelvin': temp - 273.15,
        'romer': (temp - 7.5) * 40 / 21
    }
    return conversion_dict[source]


def convert_to_celsius_lambda(temp, source):
    conversion_dict = {
        'kelvin': lambda x: x - 273.15,
        'romer': lambda x: (x - 7.5) * 40 / 21
    }
    return conversion_dict[source](temp)
```

Obviously, the two functions achieve the same goal, but via different means. Could someone help me understand the subtle difference between the two, and what the 'best' way to go on about this would be?

Comment: The first is better in this case! and the difference is that in second, your value is a function that calculate the temp and return it!

Comment: If you move `conversion_dict` with the `lambda`s **outside** of the function, you don't have to recreate it every time you call the function, which will be more efficient. Otherwise, you might as well just use the first one.

Comment: @Kasra could you explain *why* you think that, ideally using punctuation other than exclamation marks?

Comment: In the first example you are doing a normal arithmetic operation ans storing it into the dictionary. In the second one you are creating a function to be executed (which will do the same arithmetic operation when compared with the first implementation) when the key `source` is called.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how would I move it out of the function? wouldn't that resort to a dictionary of lambda functions, which is essentially the second function? Thanks for your input!

Comment: @jonrsharpe because i think there is no need to create a function and call it  for a simple operation!

Comment: @HugoSousa That's what I figured. So you'd recommend the second method? Are there ways to make it more 'optimal'?

Comment: In this case I think it is a matter of style. The lambda function use to be created to be private, fast and simple. The creation is not too heavy and it is only used once. In terms of readability, and because it is a dictionary, I find the first implementation more appropriated.

Comment: @Kasra On the other hand, in the first case, both values are being computed, but only one of them is being used (returned), so it is performing unnecessary work for the sake of "simpler" code. The lambda version does a little extra work in recreating the two functions on each call unnecessarily as well, but as another comment noted, the dictionary of lambdas could be created once outside the function and reduce that overhead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have both dictionaries being created *inside* the function, then the former will be more efficient - although the former performs two calculations when only one is needed, there is more overhead in the latter version for creating the lambdas each time it's called:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> setup = "from __main__ import convert_to_celsius, convert_to_celsius_lambda, convert_to_celsius_lambda_once"
>>> timeit.timeit("convert_to_celsius(100, 'kelvin')", setup=setup)
0.5716437913429102
>>> timeit.timeit("convert_to_celsius_lambda(100, 'kelvin')", setup=setup)
0.6484164544288618
```

---

However, if you move the dictionary of `lambda`s **outside** the function:

```
CONVERSION_DICT = {
    'kelvin': lambda x: x - 273.15,
    'romer': lambda x: (x - 7.5) * 40 / 21
}

def convert_to_celsius_lambda_once(temp, source):
    return CONVERSION_DICT[source](temp)
```

then the latter is more efficient, as the `lambda` objects are only created once, and the function only does the necessary calculation on each call:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("convert_to_celsius_lambda_once(100, 'kelvin')", setup=setup)
0.3904035060131186
```

---

Note that this will only be a benefit where the function is being called a lot (in this case, 1,000,000 times), so that the overhead of creating the two `lambda` function objects is less than the time wasted in calculating two results when only one is needed.

Comment: Thanks! Let's say that instead of two conversions, I have many many key/value pairs in the dictionary. Obviously, having the dict outside the function makes the most sense, but how does that affect the original comparison?

Comment: Use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) and find out! Basically, `convert_to_celsius_lambda` is never the right answer. I would expect more keys to make the benefit of `convert_to_celsius_lambda_once` *larger* for any more than a handful of calls, as there are now more unneeded calculations on every call to `convert_to_celsius` (but the `lambda`s still only get created once).

Comment: @RickTeachey: haha this was just a simple example. I was trying to learn more about efficient ways to utilize dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary is totally pointless, since you need to re-create it on each call but all you ever do is a single look-up. Juse use an `if`:

```
def convert_to_celsius(temp, source):
    if source == "kelvin": return temp - 273.15
    elif source == "romer": return (temp - 7.5) * 40 / 21
    raise KeyError("unknown temperature source '%s'" % source)
```

Comment: this does not acheive the same result in the default case. The OP's code throws an error if the source is not found

Comment: @njzk2 I know, that's why I had the comment. I changed it to throw a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though both achieve the same thing, the first part is more readable and faster.

In your first example you have a simple arithmetical operation which is going to be calculated once `convert_to_celsius` is called.

In the second example you calculate **only** the required temperature.

If you had the second function do an expensive calculation, then it would probably make sense to use a function instead, but for this particular example it's not required.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, neither of your options are ideal.  The first one does both calculations every time and has an unnecessary dict.  The second one has to create the lambdas every time through.  If this example is the goal then I agree with unwind to just use an if statement.  If the goal is to learn something that can be expanded to other uses, I like this approach:

```
convert_to_celsius = { 'kelvin' : lambda temp: temp - 273.15 ,
                       'romer' : lambda temp: (temp-7.5) * 40 / 21}

newtemp = convert_to_celsius[source](temp)
```

Your calculation defintions are all stored together and your function call is uncluttered and meaningful.